# How do I show map points using country codes with Highmaps?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I have looked at several examples and put together my own world map as I want it, just one detail missing. I can position map points with coordinates, but I cannot position map points with country codes.

This is my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2sk6hfvz/

```
{
    "type": "mapbubble", // <<-- change this to 'mappoint', why doesn't ghost icons show up?
    "name": "Ghosts",
    "dataLabels":
    {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "marker":
    {
        "symbol": "url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_MatteEntireSet/32/ghost.png)"
    },
    mapData: mapData,
    joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
    data:
    [
            {
                name: "Liège",
                code: "SE",
                z: 1
            },
            {
                name: "Buble",
                code: "DE",
                z: 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

Change "mapbubble" to "mappoint" in the example. Why doesn't the mappoint setting show up in the same way as mapbubble then using country codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they are not working the same way is because you have to pass x and y coordinates when you use "mappoint".

Your "goblin" data:

```
{
    "name": "Adam",
    "x": 1751,
    "y": -9500
}
```

Your "ghost" data (no "x" and "y"):

```
{
    name: "Liège",
    code: "SE",
    z: 1
}
```

If you give the "ghost" data some "x" and "y" properties, it will work. **[Please see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ws6hw4g/)**.

The other thing that you can try if you want to insert images into the map without specifying any "x" and "y" is to do it via the dataLabels. **[In this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/8s9pbwce/)**, I have created a map of the USA. Each state that has the population density smaller than 7 people per square metre will display a ghost.
If you want to go this way, there are two properties that you need to use this way:

1. `useHTML: true`  so you can have HTML `<img>` tags as data labels
2. use `formatter` instead of `format`, but please note you have to pass a function to `formatter`

`var ghostElem = '<img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Momentum_MatteEntireSet/32/ghost.png"/>';`

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    useHTML: true,
    color: 'white',
    formatter: function() { return (this.point.value <7)? ghostElem: null}
}
```

Comment: The second example was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanx! =)